# Unable to save connection remmina RDP

Tags: password, remote, rdp, remmina

I have been using windows remote desktop from remmina, what i feel so awkward is I don't see the save password button enabled, I need to frequently use my remote connection, and don't like entering username, passwords, etc, everytime...

Help me..

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @sepehr yes i did find, just rename the Quick Connect to any name if your choice, and you are done.

Comment: It's a great RDP client.  However, it'd be nice if the UI had the following workflow : _**(Save enabled by default)** -> User clicks save -> Error presented that says "Change the name from Quick Connect" -> Name is entered -> Save button works as usual_.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found out the solution: just rename the *Quick Connect* appearing in the *TextBox* to your favorite name, and it is done!

Comment: it didn't worked for me, my version is 0.9.99.1, which version do you use?

Comment: when you are trying to make a connection, you go to Connection->New, there instead of Quick Connect write any name you want, and type in the ip address, username, and password, you will get the save button enabled.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, my problem is password doesn't save not in edit box of a connection nor when I want to connect to one of defined servers. each time I have to enter password.

Comment: The only answer that actually worked.. why is the accepted password so down at the bottom?

Comment: O common that's stupid..... thanks it works

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, discovered that there is a bug using snap. Removed the snap and reinstalled from Remmina repository for Ubuntu.  Also made sure the permissions were set on `~/.remmina`.  Works fine now. This is on Xubuntu 16.10.  Seems that others have also noted that the issue relates to Xubuntu.

```
sudo snap remove remmina
```

Get repo details from [Remmina site](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/1047).

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

Comment: confirmed in 18.10

Comment: This was my only solution to get it to save any connections today on 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Check also the [flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/org.remmina.Remmina), probably more updated. [Here how to move from snap](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837)

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you own the `.remmina` folder (and all its contents).

```
$ ls -l --directory ~/.remmina/
```

Your user name should appear on the ls record like:

`drwx------ 2 username username 4096 Jan 1 12:15 /home/username/.remmina`

---

If root owns this file, You can correct the permissions like:

```
# chown --reference ~/ --recursive ~/.remmina/
```

Notes:

- `#` Implies "run as root" (eg with `sudo`), as only root may change ownership of files.
- `--reference ~/` Tells `chown` to copy the ownership of `~/`, which bash expands before the command gets executed, and points to your home folder.

Answer (score 2):

Open Remmina, then go to the `Preferences` (under three bars), then change `Remmina data folder` to your `username`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your comment was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

create directory `~/.remmina` if it doesn't exists and check what you own

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your connection, `total connection` not only your password.

Comment: well by password, i meant username, password, shared folder, don't u see the last line of my question?