# How to completely remove snap and replace with flatpak?

Tags: 19.04, snap, flatpak

I want to remove every piece of existing software/package on Ubuntu related to [snap](https://snapcraft.io) and replace with [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/).

How to completely remove snap in Ubuntu 19.04 and replace with flatpak without crashing or messing my existing system?

Answer (score 17):

You can do this manually or with [unsnap](https://github.com/popey/unsnap) (more at the end).

### Why?

[Here](https://hackaday.com/2020/06/24/whats-the-deal-with-snap-packages/) is a nice article. Basically, snap installs **only** from a **proprietary** Canonical repository, you don't have the freedom to change that. [Also](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Snap), *installs files to nonstandard locations*.

On the other hand, flatpak has its detractors too:

- [flatkill.org](https://flatkill.org/). [Here](https://theevilskeleton.gitlab.io/2021/02/11/response-to-flatkill-org.html) a response.
- [Flatpak Is Not the Future](https://ludocode.com/blog/flatpak-is-not-the-future). [Here](https://theevilskeleton.gitlab.io/2022/05/16/response-to-flatpak-is-not-the-future.html) a response.

#### Remove Snap

Probably for people who just hope Canonical give up with Snap/snapcraft (at least for Desktop):

```sh
# Stop snapd services
sudo systemctl stop snapd && sudo systemctl disable snapd

# Purge snapd
sudo apt purge -y snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap

# Remove no longer needed folders
rm -rf ~/snap
sudo rm -rf /snap /var/snap /var/lib/snapd /var/cache/snapd /usr/lib/snapd

# Prevent reinstall
sudo apt-mark hold snap snapd
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/snapd
Package: snapd
Pin: origin *
Pin-Priority: -1
EOF
```

If you are unsure about removing snap completely, you can at least reduce it at its minimum: [remove snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331196/is-there-a-way-to-use-ubuntu-software-center-without-snaps), remove snap plugin from GNOME Software; and of course remove any snap also available as flatpak, like [Ungoogled Chromium](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.Eloston.UngoogledChromium) <sup>[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206502/349837)</sup>.
Worth to mention that ["it's possible to remove all the snaps, and remove snapd... the desktop will function fine"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317194/how-do-i-find-out-which-of-my-apps-are-snaps-also-can-i-go-snap-less#comment2242839_1317202) (from a former snap developer; see unsnap below). `gnome-...` snaps [are just backends for GTK snap apps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345181/349837).

```sh
sudo snap remove snap-store  # And anything you don't use of  snap list
sudo apt purge gnome-software-plugin-snap
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

**Sources**:

- [How to uninstall snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280707/how-to-uninstall-snap)
- [How to remove snap completely without losing the Chromium browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179273/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-the-chromium-browser?rq=1)
- [Completely Remove Snap from Ubuntu Linux [Tutorial]](https://www.debugpoint.com/2022/04/remove-snap-ubuntu/)

#### Remove snap also from [command-not-found](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/command-not-found)

Is also possible to change [command-not-found](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommandNotFoundMagic) behavior to stop suggesting installing snap packages (*Command 'something' not found, but can be installed with:*), tuning `advice` method from `CommandNotFound` class on `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py` (`/usr/share/doc/command-not-found/README.md` is obsolete). Near the end (line 365) add `snaps, mispell_snaps = ['','']` to force an empty result.

```py
         packages = self.get_packages(command)
         snaps, mispell_snaps = self.get_snaps(command)
         snaps, mispell_snaps = ['','']
         logging.debug("got debs: %s snaps: %s" % (packages, snaps))
```

This applies to bash. On zsh `/usr/lib/command-not-found` seeems to be used.

#### [Install Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/)

1. **Install Flatpak on Ubuntu 18.10 or later** (check [here](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) for older versions).

   ```sh
   sudo apt install flatpak
   ```
2. **Install the Software Flatpak plugin**: The Flatpak plugin for the Software app makes it possible to install apps without needing the command line. To install, run:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
   ```
3. **Add the Flathub repository**: Flathub is the best place to get Flatpak apps. To enable it, run:

   ```sh
   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   ```

   Add `--user` if you'll install per-user apps.
4. **Restart your system** (`reboot`).

To adjust flatpak permissions check [Flatseal](https://github.com/tchx84/Flatseal) (`flatpak install flatseal`).

#### Common commands

Using `flatpak install/uninstall nameOfTheApp` usually is enough. It will run a fuzzy search and suggest alternatives.

- `flatpak run name`: Run an installed application.
- `flatpak install remote name`: Install an application from a remote source. `--user` will install per-user. Examples:

  ```
  $ flatpak install flathub org.gnome.gedit
  $ flatpak --user install flathub org.gnome.gedit//3.30
  $ flatpak --user install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gnome.gedit.flatpakref
  ```
- `flatpak list`: List all installed applications and runtimes.
- `flatpak update`: Update all installed applications and runtimes.
- `flatpak remove name`: Remove an installed application. `--unused` also remove unused refs on the system.
- `flatpak info name`: Show information about an installed application.

### unsnap

[Ex snap developer Alan Pope](https://twitter.com/popey/status/1380139900108963848) had developed [unsnap](https://github.com/popey/unsnap) (currently on pre-alpha status) to *Quickly migrate from using snap packages to flatpaks:*

> Quickly and easily migrate from using `snap` for applications to `flatpak`. unsnap runs as a two-stage process. unsnap itself generates the scripts to do the actual migration. This enables users to view and/or edit the scripts prior to execution to validate or tweak them.

[pop-transition](https://github.com/pop-os/transition) is a similar project.

### Related

- [Privacy Guides: Linux Overview](https://www.privacyguides.org/linux-desktop/overview/)
- **Other apps technologies and sources**

  - [AppImage](https://appimage.org/)/[AppImageHub](https://www.appimagehub.com/)
  - [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/): The missing package manager for macOS (or Linux).
  - [PyPI](https://pypi.org/): The Python Package Index (PyPI) is a repository of software for the Python programming language. [`pip`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/): A tool for installing and managing Python packages.

Comment: It's interesting that this came from Pope. He's been a proponent of snaps forever 

Comment: @matigo [He left Canonical in 2021](https://twitter.com/popey/status/1511346989245554698). That he's willing to spend his time to start this project I guess can tell us something..

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Thanks to doug. It feels so clean now, all snap removed.

> [image: screenshot]