# VLC .config question

Tags: vlc

I'm just mainly asking because I don't want to mess up anything on my computer.

I am trying to do this: [VLC is still running even I closed it already. How to I close it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250477/vlc-is-still-running-even-i-closed-it-already-how-to-i-close-it)

So I found the `.config` file in files, put the VLC `f.conf` file in the trash, and, later put it back. I did not delete it in any way.

Now, my brother told me that might mess with VLC.
I'm just curious if this is true, and if it is what I need to do (from the instructions from the link)

Comment: It does not mess with VLC. The config file is either there or it isn't. If it isn't, at the time you start VLC, a new one will be created. The point of deleting it in the linked answer is, I think, that other modifications that the OP may have made do not interfere with the solution, which comes down to removing hardware acceleration.

Comment: Dear jos, Thank you. I just tried vlc, following the instructions I gave and it works fine. I guess my brother was messing with me after all.