# How can I stop apt from installing snap packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` for some reason installs not a proper apt-get package but is installing the chromium snap.

I am aware that blocking such installs will not magically establish a maintained package, and would result in an installation failure. But I prefer to get error and install manually - from source or in unlikely cases from snap.

I want to never install anything using snap (for start, due to Snap Store closed-source practice). Especially not silently when I install using `apt-get`.

[How can I disable snaps in gnome-software centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre) is not answering my question as I want to get rid of snap infestation in `apt` - not in gnome-software-center.

Comment: Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1317194/1157519

Comment: @Levente Thanks! Unfortunately it is not helping - I want installation to fail if it would require installing snap with apt-get.

Comment: The Chromium browser is not packaged as a *deb* and hasn't been for numerous releases (well before 20.04 anyway; 18.04 had it as a *deb* package but late 2018 it first appeared as *snap* - see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-chromium-snap-as-a-replacement-for-the-deb/7978 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/intent-to-provide-chromium-as-a-snap-only/5987 ; May-2018).  It's available as *deb* only as stub so users don't get errors telling them package isn't found (it just loads the *snap* for them).  I find `discover` is pretty easy to pick *snaps* and *debs*

Comment: @guiverc I am fine with being unable to install Chromium with apt. In fact, if it requires snap - I want to be unable to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable snaps in gnome-software centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre)

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is wise... You risk making your system unable to take updates.. which are often done via *deb* if it's technologically easier than getting users to run a command (and impossible via *snap*).

Comment: @guiverc I am fine with that. If my system is unable to work without snap, I am OK with changing to a different distribution.

Comment: @guiverc I am not sure what code provided in https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre is actually doing, but it seems dubious that "you'll not see snaps in gnome or ubuntu software app" would also fix apt.

Comment: Lubuntu works well with *snaps* disabled (on boxes with only 1GB of RAM, it often makes sense to do so; though I tended to disable only, as there were times when I found it useful to enable it.. esp. *upgrade* time).   I won't advise, but if you look Linux Mint is downstream of Ubuntu & only recently disabled/hacked-it so it did what you want, but problems soon appeared and parts of it had to be reversed... I don't think it's wise so won't help sorry (but disabling snaps is easier & what I'd recommend)

Comment: **Debian** : No chromium snap  https://packages.debian.org/sid/chromium  ....   Example Ubuntu 20.04 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HsuZQNyKNq9L1XcE1clacFLwiRK9gDS3?usp=sharing

Comment: This is why I'm still on 18.04LTS, and will leave the Ubuntu world when it goes EOL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides setting files in `/etc/apt`, you can run `apt-mark` to prevent anything requiring `snapd` from installing, just after purge snapd:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold snapd
```

For example, installing `firefox` in Ubuntu 22.04 (which is a snapd-based package) gives you an error:

```
$ sudo apt install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox : PreDepends: snapd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The only way to break this rule is to do it explicitly:

```
$ sudo apt install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  snapd
The following held packages will be changed:
  snapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 102 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Also, you can undo the effect via:

```
$ sudo apt-mark unhold snapd
```

Answer (score 33):

You have to remove snapd from the system by

```
sudo apt-get autopurge snapd
```

and then create special configuration file for APT, as LinuxMint [did](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snap.html#disabled-snap-store-in-linux-mint-20):

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref
# To prevent repository packages from triggering the installation of Snap,
# this file forbids snapd from being installed by APT.
# For more information: https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snap.html

Package: snapd
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
EOF
```

This will prevent Snaps installation in future.

Comment: Is it safe to immediately perform the autopurge? Many tutorials involve first disabling snap, removing the individual snaps, etc. Perhaps yes, but this may then leave unused files and folders behind.

Comment: The configuration script will do for us what is needed.

Comment: @N0rbert so by doing this, how do I install Firefox through apt? It depends on snapd

Comment: If you still want Firefox, first uninstall the Snap, then add the file above, then get Firefox from one of a few different places, as listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369159/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-firefox

Comment: I can't find evidence for the existence of an "autopurge" command.

Comment: @odigity The `autopurge` command exists for both `apt-get` and `apt`, and it's a shortcut for `autoremove --purge`. A piece of documentation about it was added to the apt source code in 2022: https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/c9c1a1cb8471ff5cdb38b3c94cb96071370a091b/doc/apt-get.8.xml#L258