# Uninstalling a Gnome version

Tags: gnome, uninstall, 21.10

I'm using **Ubuntu 21.10** with **Gnome 40** and i found in Ubuntu Software three different version of Gnome.

[image: T]

I wanted to see if they are disabled to uninstall them but don't show if their disabled or enabled.(snap list --all to see if them are disabled or not)

[image: Snap command in Terminal]

Should I uninstall them?It is safe?

Comment: Gnome 40 is still beta for ubuntu 21.04 , So this problem couldn't be solved exactly as it still has a lot of undiscovered bugs

Comment: @Algnis OP is using 21.10, where GNOME 40 (stable version) is available.

Comment: He first mentioned 21.04 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the GNOME backends for the snap apps, which use those versions of GNOME as their dependency. In case you are using snap apps, don't remove them.

In case you don't plan to use snaps, then you can [remove snaps](https://askubuntu.com/q/1035915/124466) altogether (which will remove those shared GNOME versions as well) and further, [prevent](https://askubuntu.com/q/1345385/124466) it from automatically getting installed again.

Removing a GNOME backend by force, without uninstalling all the snaps which depend on it would be a bad idea.