# How do I decrease my boot time [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: boot, 20.04

My PC specs -> Intel i5, Nvidia 1050 Ti, 8 GB Ram and Ubuntu is installed on a HDD.

**systemd-analyze command result**

`Startup finished in 5.007s (kernel) + 1min 49.037s (userspace) = 1min 54.044s graphical.target reached after 1min 48.083s in userspace`

**systemd-analyze blame command result**

````
46.528s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
42.233s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
32.650s dev-sdb3.device                                                          
28.816s snapd.service                                                            
21.598s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
18.733s dev-loop31.device                                                        
18.664s dev-loop34.device                                                        
18.372s dev-loop35.device                                                        
18.340s dev-loop28.device                                                        
17.980s dev-loop30.device                                                        
17.804s dev-loop29.device                                                        
17.803s dev-loop27.device                                                        
17.803s dev-loop32.device                                                        
16.889s dev-loop33.device                                                        
16.590s dev-loop23.device                                                        
16.560s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                       
16.498s dev-loop15.device                                                        
16.494s dev-loop24.device                                                        
16.252s dev-loop25.device                                                        
16.238s dev-loop14.device                                                        
15.959s dev-loop11.device                                                        
15.734s dev-loop21.device                                                        
15.602s dev-loop16.device                                                        
15.435s dev-loop13.device                                                        
15.420s dev-loop18.device                                                        
15.399s dev-loop26.device                                                        
15.332s udisks2.service                                                          
15.254s libvirtd.service                                                         
14.799s dev-loop4.device                                                         
14.346s dev-loop20.device                                                        
14.315s dev-loop12.device                                                        
14.174s dev-loop22.device                                                        
13.754s dev-loop17.device                                                        
13.569s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
13.054s dev-loop19.device                                                        
11.360s ModemManager.service                                                     
10.972s dev-loop8.device                                                         
10.904s NetworkManager.service                                                   
10.263s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
10.261s bluetooth.service                                                        
10.233s dundee.service                                                           
10.185s polkit.service                                                           
10.072s dev-loop3.device                                                         
10.061s dev-loop6.device                                                         
10.007s dev-loop9.device                                                         
 9.876s dev-loop1.device                                                         
 9.434s ofono.service                                                            
 9.254s switcheroo-control.service                                               
 9.247s thermald.service                                                         
 9.235s systemd-machined.service                                                 
 9.235s systemd-logind.service                                                   
 9.162s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
 8.539s dev-loop10.device                                                        
 8.399s vboxdrv.service                                                          
 7.747s dev-loop7.device                                                         
 7.233s dev-loop5.device                                                         
 7.202s dev-loop2.device                                                         
 7.187s fwupd.service                                                            
 6.517s gpu-manager.service                                                      
 4.654s dev-loop0.device                                                         
 3.914s apport.service                                                           
 3.897s user@125.service                                                         
 3.688s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
 3.451s secureboot-db.service                                                    
 3.391s grub-common.service                                                      
 3.362s systemd-sysctl.service                                                   
 3.078s gdm.service                                                              
 3.024s systemd-resolved.service                                                 
 2.893s snap-bare-5.mount                                                        
 2.662s snap-brave-134.mount                                                     
 2.645s snap-brave-135.mount                                                     
 2.496s snap-code-78.mount                                                       
 2.404s vpnagentd.service                                                        
 2.375s snap-code-79.mount                                                       
 2.373s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
 2.353s snap-core-11798.mount                                                    
 2.233s snap-core-11993.mount                                                    
 2.183s snap-core18-2128.mount                                                   
 2.167s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
 2.161s plymouth-start.service                                                   
 2.154s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                      
 2.094s snap-core18-2246.mount                                                   
 2.033s snap-core20-1081.mount                                                   
 2.024s snap-core20-1169.mount                                                   
 2.003s snap-discord-128.mount                                                   
 2.001s snap-discord-130.mount                                                   
 1.998s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                  
 1.942s rsyslog.service                                                          
 1.753s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount                                  
 1.751s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                   
 1.750s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount                                   
 1.739s snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
 1.737s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount                                  
 1.732s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                           
 1.717s lm-sensors.service                                                       
 1.710s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1519.mount                                  
 1.691s nvidia-persistenced.service                                              
 1.644s apparmor.service                                                         
 1.558s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2dcore20-14.mount          
 1.556s snap-mari0-6.mount                                                       
 1.554s snap-okular-109.mount                                                    
 1.552s snap-pomatez-2.mount                                                     
 1.418s systemd-modules-load.service                                             
 1.406s pppd-dns.service                                                         
 1.366s snap-qt513-23.mount                                                      
 1.199s snap-qt513-24.mount                                                      
 1.196s snap-snap\x2dstore-542.mount                                             
 1.079s ua-messaging.service                                                     
 1.061s keyboard-setup.service                                                   
 1.018s systemd-random-seed.service                                              
  955ms snap-snap\x2dstore-547.mount                                             
  952ms snap-snapd-13270.mount                                                   
  946ms tlp.service                                                              
  942ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                 
  862ms upower.service                                                           
  851ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                             
  820ms libvirt-guests.service                                                   
  789ms snap-snapd-13640.mount                                                   
  787ms snap-spotify-53.mount                                                    
  681ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-110.mount                                           
  649ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-109.mount                                           
  640ms qemu-kvm.service                                                         
  614ms modprobe@drm.service                                                     
  591ms snap-whatsie-48.mount                                                    
  590ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                       
  572ms snap-whatsie-46.mount                                                    
  555ms lvm2-monitor.service                                                     
  481ms colord.service                                                           
  474ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-36F0\x2d11BE.service                    
  463ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-160.mount                                            
  371ms systemd-journald.service                                                 
  340ms snapd.seeded.service                                                     
  335ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                
  302ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                               
  302ms ufw.service                                                              
  300ms boot-efi.mount                                                           
  294ms vboxautostart-service.service                                            
  294ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service                                          
  290ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                      
  289ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                         
  287ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                   
  286ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                 
  283ms blk-availability.service                                                 
  281ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                
  272ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-163.mount                                            
  265ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b35c9b73\x2d6bcc\x2d4034\x2dad5c\x2d3fbbd12e74b0.swap
  212ms kerneloops.service                                                       
  210ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                            
  197ms hddtemp.service                                                          
  172ms user@1000.service                                                        
  166ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                              
   93ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                           
   82ms console-setup.service                                                    
   73ms vboxweb-service.service                                                  
   51ms setvtrgb.service                                                         
   46ms plymouth-read-write.service                                              
   37ms geoclue.service                                                          
   27ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                             
   21ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                     
   18ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                     
   10ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                            
    5ms alsa-restore.service                                                     
    3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                            
    3ms openvpn.service                                                          
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                  
    1ms libvirtd.socket                                                          
  996us snapd.socket```
````

Comment: Check the answer here: [Is it possible to make Ubuntu 20.04 boot faster?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster)

Comment: You have a lot of apps in snap format: you can try to install the version available via apt and remove the snap version.

Comment: Replace snap apps with apt versions, and consider [removing snap altogether](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466).

Comment: @24601 My boot time is 36 seconds in a 4 year old HDD. SSD is not necessarily required to get a boot time of ~40 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop apt from installing snap packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345385/how-can-i-stop-apt-from-installing-snap-packages) . Run `snap list` at first and save its output if safe place.

Comment: Yes I removed snap packages and followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster this method so now I have 53 seconds of booting time