# Ubuntu 22.04, save dialog is maximized and not active

Tags: dialog

After Ubuntu 22.04 installation, just little problem with save dialog.

Example, in case of save file in web browser (chrome), save dialog is maximized and not active, so I must click on it and then save dialog is active.

In past, it was active immedietelly without clicking, so in case of save file, I can write name of file without click.

Maybe problem is maximized window of save dialog? But I don't know how to "normalize" this window.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Buggy behavior of xdg-desktop-portal-gtk affecting containerized applications (snap, flatpak and appimage)

Comment: @vanadium I am not using snap, flatpak or appimage for this case. I installed classical via apt.

Comment: I confirm the issue with Google Chrome, which indeed is installed as a .deb. I suspect they are using the GTK4 dialog also through xdg-desktop-portal. The focus issue only happens on subsequent times you open the dialog, not the first time. Happens always, not because your dialog is maximized.

Comment: See https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/issues/137. This will happen not only to containerized apps, but also to regular apps using the portal to display native dialogs.

Comment: @genderbee For better or for worse, Ubuntu now installs snap packages even when using `apt`, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345385/how-can-i-stop-apt-from-installing-snap-packages

If you want to avoid these containerized packages you either need to follow special instructions in one of the answers there, or switch to a different distribution such as Arch that does not favor these packages.

Answer (score 1):

Issue persist in 23.04
(save dialog not active)

Not a solution, but as a work-around, what I do is using ALT+Tab twice to make activate the save dialogue, so that I can rename file without using the mouse.