# I uninstalled snap. Is it safe to delete /var/lib/snapd/?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, snap

For reason unknown to me `/var/lib/snapd/` remains littering my system after I have get rid of snap.

Is it safe to remove that folder?

Comment: Did you uninstall those snaps before uninstalling snap itself? Otherwise, you might want to reinstall it to remove the snaps first.

Comment: You can find all remaining signatures of snap with `locate snap`. You may first have to install `plocate` with `sudo apt install plocate` and run `sudo updatedb` to generate the database.

Answer (score 2):

Snap can be safely removed from an Ubuntu install. The system directory `/var/lib/snapd/` is solely used by the snap system, and thus can be safely removed if it was left behind after installation.

That the directory was not removed leads to suspect that you did not remove all snap packages before removing the snap software. In uninstall scripts, directories are left behind if they still contain data not installed by the `.deb` software package, in this case `snapd`.

Next time, use the `autopurge` option as explained in this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345401/558158) to remove both the `snapd` daemon *and* the installed snaps.