# Replacing snap with flatpak. What will happen when I upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, snap, flatpak

I'm considering replacing snap with flatpak. What happens during a version upgrade of Ubuntu? Is the Ubuntu upgrade programmed to reinstall snap and what is the risk of pinning or holding snap from being reinstalled?

I would like to avoid having to purge snap on every upgrade and don't want to risk ending up with a broken system because some key system component has become a snap package.

Comment: Check here: [How to uninstall snap?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1285102/1037999) If you pin the `snap` package, it won't be reinstalled. I've tested it from 20.04 to 20.10, 20.10 to 21.04 and 21.04 to 21.10 transitions.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)   *Ubuntu jammy is still in alpha; yes feature freeze has hit, but changes can still occur with SRUs so it's still a partial unknown*

Comment: You may eventually lose printing: [CUPS](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cups-interface-merged-into-snapd-additional-steps-to-complete/28653) is in the (slow, methodical) process of transitioning from deb to snap. The developers cite too few volunteers to maintain and package and test multiple versions for different releases of Ubuntu -- the snap offers a significant reduction in their workload. More volunteers to do the work would, of course, preserve the deb option.

Comment: @Lorenz Keel, why not post as an answer?

Comment: @vanadium the question may be considered duplicated, so I preferred not to post an answer, but nonetheless I've put one, with some lines about pinning (so that it's not exactly a duplicate of the link I posted before).

Comment: Keep in mind more and more of the GNOME environment is snapped nowadays, if you are using stock ubuntu and such you are going to eventually break your desktop environment if you don't keep snaps.  The same with CUPS as well.  And Firefox (which is now already fully `snap`ped).

Comment: @ThomasWard Alan Pope (former snap and current [unsnap](https://github.com/popey/unsnap) developer) [mention that "_it's possible to remove all the snaps, and remove snapd... the desktop will function fine_"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317194/how-do-i-find-out-which-of-my-apps-are-snaps-also-can-i-go-snap-less#comment2242839_1317202)

Comment: @PabloBianchi the *desktop* might but Canonical and Ubuntu are moving pretty hard towards trying to snap what they can into the Desktop edition.  Eventually that statement won't be accurate.

Comment: @ThomasWard Several times Canonical have undone very unpopular decisions. Eventually, they'll make snap completely FOSS or terminate it. From the time being, snap is not mandatory, and we (FOSS advocates) could/should help to [move away from it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837)

Answer (score 3):

`apt` gives the chance to [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) a package. Further details about pinning are available using the terminal command `man 5 apt_preferences`.

The "Pin-Priority" parameter, in your specific case, can be used to prevent the re-installation of `snapd` package by giving it a negative priority.

Create a file `no-snap.pref` by issuing in a terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-snap.pref
```

and then copy the following content in it:

```sh
# To install snapd, specify its version with 'apt install snapd=VERSION'
# where VERSION is the version of the snapd package you want to install.
Package: snapd
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

You can still install `snapd` if you want, but you need to explicitly set the package version in the `sudo apt install` command: you don't need to delete the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/no-snap.pref` file.

I've tested this procedure from 20.04 to 20.10 + 20.10 to 21.04 + 21.04 to 21.10 transitions. However, consider that for the GNOME variant of Ubuntu, the number of packages distributed as snap is increasing, and for some of them the decision has been taken not by Canonical but by the package distributor itself (for instance, Mozilla for `firefox`). In the future the removal of `snapd` may not be harmless.

Comment: Note that if you are using the GNOME desktop variant of Ubuntu Desktop you will be sacrificing a lot of functionality as it's mostly snapped now instead of debian packaged.  This will cause some issues if you aren't careful.

Comment: @Thomas Ward, for what concerns me, I'm fully aware. However, I'll add a note in my answer.