# If I install a snap package, will the config files be carried over and the already installed deb package be removed automatically?

Tags: apt, software-installation, snap, thunderbird, deb

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, Thunderbird is installed as deb package (version 91). I'd like to use the new Thunderbird version 102, which is only available as a snap package.

What will happen if I say `sudo snap install thunderbird`?

Will my TB config and mail folders be carried over? Will the deb package be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Both installations of the app would work independently one from the other. The deb package won't be uninstalled. The snap one won't take the deb config.

You can also have a [flatpak alternative](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.Thunderbird), which much more people seem to prefer. Same with a lot of other apps like Firefox or Brave.

**Related**: [How to completely remove snap and replace with flatpak?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837)

Comment: But when upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, the Firefox deb package was migrated to the snap version without losing any data. Was this a special-made upgrade script from the Ubuntu team?

Comment: [Yes](https://news.itsfoss.com/ubuntu-firefox-snap-default/), is a controversial decision, already done with Chromium.

Comment: @foobar in that case, [there's a placeholder apt package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/firefox) which causes the installation of the snap package. In a sense, you still have both apt and snap packages installed when upgrading.