# Why can't Ubuntu use the command-not-found command?

Tags: command-line, apt, debian

I use Ubuntu 22.04, and I found that Ubuntu has preinstalled the command-not-found package, but the `command-not-found` command cannot be used.

Because Debian's command-not-found package provides the `command-not-found` command that looks up programs not currently installed but available from the repositories.

May I ask whether Ubuntu has modified this package?

Any answer is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be used"? How did you try to use it?

Comment: Yes, Canonical modified the package to add its snap thing. I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837) a way to remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command itself (actually it's an executable Python script) lives in `/usr/lib/`, which is not usually in a user's `PATH`. But you can certainly run it if you wish, e.g.

```
$ /usr/lib/command-not-found cpufetch
Command 'cpufetch' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install cpufetch  # version 1.04, or
sudo apt  install cpufetch  # version 1.01+git20211208+40b13bc-2
See 'snap info cpufetch' for additional versions.
```

However it's typically run automagically by the bash shell, via its `command_not_found_handle` hook function:

```
$ declare -f -p command_not_found_handle
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`command-not-found` is not a command to be used. If you enter a command corresponding to a package which is not installed, Ubuntu will offer you to install the package.

For example, if you write `cpufetch`, Ubuntu will offer you to install it with

```
sudo apt install cpufetch
```

Comment: Sometimes you may need a "clean" way (ie. without typing a wrong command on a command line) to display what package provides a particular command, so there may be a few rare cases when you'd actually want to use the `command-not-found` command.